# Changing View + Sending variables to the view programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

I have got a function that changes the view correctly but it is not passing the variables to the next view. I am really not an expert in Swift and I do not know where is the error in my code:

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PaymentVC") as! PaymentViewController
self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    newViewController.num_pal = num_words
    newViewController.l_origen = l_source
    newViewController.l_destino = l_target
    newViewController.espec = espec
    newViewController.user = user
    newViewController.pass = pass
    newViewController.texto = texto
    newViewController.modificado = modificado
    newViewController.texto_ant = texto_ant
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)` should be after passing data, just put it after all that `newViewController.texto_ant = texto_ant`

Comment: Great Juicy! Thank you very much, in 11 min I will accept your answer

Comment: Btw, do you know why my navigation controller disappears after doing this function? I have tried with: `self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)` in `viewDidLoad()` and many more but none seems to work...

Comment: you should call `self.navigationController?.pushViewController` then, present shows new `UIViewController` not in navigation stack. @alberzyzz

Comment: Thank you again for your time. Should I only replace `self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)` with `self.navigationController?.pushViewController`?

Comment: you should replace `self.present` with this, you shouldn't call `self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)` at all

Comment: Worked! I am grateful to you.